# Excluded from company award - maternity leave

Tags: discrimination, leave-of-absence, parental-leave

My company gave yearly awards recently. I learned that my whole team got one for "great customer implementations". I'm on maternity leave which started in October but I did the same job as them up until 8th month of pregnancy. And with results that were always praised somehow. Is it normal to omit me only due to the fact that I'm on prolonged leave? Or should I ask HR for the reason? How would you approach that?

Comment: Are you considered a part of the team as of now? many organizations allow long leaves, but that does not mean they'll retain your assignment to a project / team. You are still and employee and have all benefits, but your team assignment might have changed.

Comment: To elaborate, when you return, you might be reporting to same manager, but working with a different team altogether (based on the requirements at that time).

Comment: @Ola_S: was this just an award, as in receiving a fancy piece of paper then everyone stood together and smiled for a photo? Or did this also come attached with a "money award"?

Comment: What specifically are you missing out on by not having been mentioned? Is this purely a matter of getting public credit, or are there actual rewards (bonus, extra leave, ...) attached to it? Is this more important than a simple "they probably forgot to mention absent people"?

Comment: Probably your award is sitting in the managers desk drawer waiting for you to come back.

Answer (score 5):

I'll assume that in your country maternity leave works somewhat like sick leave. You are out for a specified amount of time, but you will return to your old job with no changes.

Common sense wise, a team award goes to the team, not to specific members. So if your team was mentioned with members by name, your name should be there, too. You are on that team, just temporarily not at work. I would also expect that your stand-in if you have one would be mentioned too, even if they were only on the team for a few months. That's what makes a team. Otherwise it's just a bunch of individuals coincidentally sharing an office.

With that expectation in mind, find out a few things: did your whole team get the award, or was it actually specific people? Was it the year of good work that earned them the award, or was it a specific action at a specific time (that you may have missed, lets say those people did a boatload of unpaid overtime in December to finish a project before 2021).

Lets assume it actually *was* a team award and you *should* be on there. Your best strategy is to let your team handle this. They are at work, they do it on company time, they are the one's that got official praise, their voice now holds weight and credibility. If you say "I should be there with them" it sounds egoistical, if they say "she should be here with us" it sounds like team spirit.

Contact your team, ask them the above questions (maybe it was indeed something specific you missed, not a years award) and if it becomes clear that it is a teams award for the years work, ask them if they can inquire why you're not on it. It might be just a mistake in HR, to pull the wrong set of records. HR that probably printed the award probably never saw the team, they just got a mail from management with the team name and printed a list of active members. Who knows why you are not on that list, maybe their software is shitty and does not support maternity leave and their workaround is to temporarily assign you to the "maternity leave" team in the software. Or they have a filter called "active members" to find out how strong the team is right now and you are not in it. They should have picked another filter.

Or maybe you really were not considered. Then it should be the job of your team to stand up for you and demand you be in it.

That said, as non-monetary company rewards are not regulated in any way, you have no real recourse if the company *really* says "no, we don't think so, we don't give awards to people that were not here for the full year.". It's just a piece of paper. Since you are on maternity leave, be happy about the the important things and real people in your life, don't worry about a self-printed piece of paper from a legal entity that doesn't even breathe.

Comment: thank you for your comment, it's really good advise/explanation. I do believe I should have got this award as it went to the team for the whole year (and I was there for most of the time), but you're right, getting too bothered by it makes no sense. It's not the first time when I was made non-existent due to maternity leave though, so I'll probably just work on my CV in meantime and look for something else after the leave, as it made me question company's culture (well, not only this...).

Comment: Depends on the company but some have policies to leave those on leave alone. There are both positive and negative aspects to such a policy.

Comment: Brian makes a good point.  When my wife went out on maternity leave, she was prohibited from having any contact with work other than for HR reasons (ie. benefit coordination, etc).  The policy was in place b/c if she were to answer an email or attend a meeting, it would have (from a legal perspective) ended her leave... and she couldn't go right back out on a new maternity leave.  The policy was in place to protect her from losing the benefits of the leave window.  Don't assume the worst.  You can always clear it up when you officially return to work.